# Validity of mathematical induction

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Are there philosophical positions that reject the validity of mathematical proofs by induction? If so, what are the implications?

I know that mathematical intuitionists reject the law of the excluded middle, and therefore proof by contradiction, demanding instead a constructive proof. So I was wondering whether a similar position can be taken with respect to mathematical induction? Since induction in a sense relies on the existence of an infinite number of natural numbers, I can imagine that someone who does not acknowledge the existence of real or potential infinities may also reject mathematical induction.

Comment: Strict finitists and [ultrafinitists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism) reject full scale mathematical induction, more recent authors also reject it because it fails for the so-called vague predicates, like “number of grains in a heap”. [Tsujishita's Alternative Mathematics without Actual Infinity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.2193) is a comprehensive recent review.

Comment: I think the issue of [predicativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity) also deserves mention here. For instance [Edward Nelson](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/papers/e.pdf) (a renowned mathematician) used it as an argument to reject mathematical induction. See also [here](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/papers/warn.pdf).

Comment: Induction does not rely on an infinite number of natural numbers, it is completely constructive.  It means that when given a number, you can follow the algorithm to directly produce a finite proof.  So for any number there is a proof, and so the statement is proven for all numbers.  You only need that each number exists, not that we can use the Natural Numbers as a completed infinity.

Comment: @jobermark It is not "completely" constructive since it relies on imagined ability to continue an algorithmic process indefinitely. Ultrafinitists object to entertaining such possibilities and reject potential infinity along with the actual one. Since even big enough finite is humanly and physically impossible imagining it may well be wishful thinking. Modal skeptics generally reach similar conclusions.

Comment: @Conifold, that first comment really is an *answer* to this question, and a very good one.  Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Induction, finite or infinite, has nothing whatsoever to do with the Axiom of Choice.

Induction happens across the "ordinals", the spine of all models of ZF.   Induction can be performed over any well-ordered set or class...and every well-ordered set can be put in one-to-one correspondence with an ordinal. From this, one can prove that any well-ordered proper class *is* the ordinals up to isomorphism.

This has nothing to say about sets which are far from the ordinals, and which might not be well-orderable.

Comment: @jobermark The thing about induction is that it's a definition chasing its own tail. We "intuitively" define the natural numbers as the set of entities which has a bunch of second order properties, including reflection and "true" induction -- and then we go back and use that definition to justify induction.

It really comes down to a statement of faith: if you "believe" in the natural numbers, then you "believe" in induction, and vice versa. Me, I "believe" in V, the set theoretic universe -- but I also recognize that's a bizarre and absurd claim.

Comment: @JWLM  Actually no, if you believe in algorithms, you believe in induction.  No dependency upon the class of natural numbers.  Only in bizarre places like FOL that unnaturally rip time out of consideration is induction at all weird.  So for intuitionists or construcivists it is not a problem at all, nor does it require infinitely many axioms.  It just requires iteration, which Classical mathematics dodges to a crazy degree by having infinitely many axioms.

Comment: @Conifold  Yes, an algorithm is completely constructive.  I can loop.  Infinity only intrudes if you play games to avoid temporal sequence.  This is not an arbitrary ascending loop.  it is a strictly descending one.  For any number, it only counts down.  Not at all the same as following an infinite sequence upward.  So given a  number, I get a proof by executing an algorithm.  I don't have to rely on any larger number other than the one I was given, which by being given, clearly exists.  You can balk at anything, but this has nothing to do with finitism under any stated definition..

Comment: @jobermark You're confusing the validity of induction up to a certain (arbitrary) finite value and mathematical induction across an infinite set. Inductive proof up to a finite value -- which is what you actually depend upon to validate any application of an algorithm -- consists of the proof of a single long but valid statement of *first-order logic*. Infinitary induction makes a claim about an infinitely-long, and hence invalid, statement.  That's a very nice distinction, but it is also critical. It's *exactly* that difference which leads to the Second Incompleteness Theorem.

Comment: @JWLM,  No, I am coming from intuitionism.  I don't really believe in the completed infinity you claim is absolutely necessary, but I still believe in induction.  Arbitrary choice and a completed infinity are only related if you insist on an atemporal reality.  So your argument insists that Intuitionism as a position does not exist.  You are missing a subtlety some of us find very important.

Comment: @jobermark You're confusing two very different things: the question of whether you accept or reject cut and whether the natural numbers are well-founded. Those are completely different. You can reject the first and accept the second, and, bizarre as it might sound, accept the first and reject the second -- just look at any non-standard model of the natural numbers. If we "live" in one of those, then we're merely deluded in believing that induction is valid.

Comment: @JWLM  If you keep telling me how I am confused, as though you can  read my mind, I am going to consider you insane and not worth interacting with.  Make *your* point, or really point out an error, instead of guessing what I am thinking.

Comment: @JWLM Arbitrary choice is not about well-foundedness.  A correct induction means that if I choose an arbitrary number, I can execute a finite algorithm, finintely many times and construct the text of a proof for the given case.  No infinities necessary.  For someone like Kleene, the issue around induction is whether a proof needs to already be finite, or whether it can be constructed at need.  Since classical mathematics does not embody time, there is no construction at need, and induction becomes spooky.

Comment: @jobermark It makes no difference whether the loop is ascending or descending. Execution time is not equal to the size of the input, and you can not physically loop 10...0 times because the universe will end sooner. Your belief that the algorithm is still executable (in whatever sense) is just that, a belief that others may not share. Ultrafinitists are "far more constructivist" than intuitionists, and modal skeptics would reject whatever notion of modality you need to explain what "executable" means in such cases.

Comment: @Conifold OK, so some random person can invent 'ultra' finitism of the nth degree.  But finite is finite.  Period.  Deciding I can have the algorithm be 3 but not 1000000 times longer than the original number is nonsense.  This is just arbitrariness invented to address nothing in particular other than someone's whim.  The algorithm can't "continue indefinitely", the step in an induction is finite, and so is the number of steps.  So I don't imagine what you claim I imagine.  Constructible and finite have definitions.  Ultrafinite just doesn't.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We should distinguish between induction over finite sets and over infinite sets. I'm not aware of any philosophical position that would reject a proof of the statement "For all n less than 100, the sum 1 + 2+ ... + n = n(n+1)/2" using induction on n. Induction only relies on each number n having a successor n+1 that behaves arithmetically the way we expect, and this can be checked explicitly for every number up to 100.

But when you say "For all natural numbers n, the sum 1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n+1)/2," and prove it by induction, you're implicitly making a claim that the natural numbers exist. Certain flavors of [Finitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism) reject the existence of the natural numbers or any infinite sets. More specifically, so-called classical finitists are alright with statements like "every natural number has a successor," because in principle, given any large but finite n, one could write down a proof of finite length that proves the statement for all numbers less than n. So I believe they would have no qualms with inductive proofs. But strict finitism does not accept the existence even of *potentially infinite* objects, so they would not allow themselves to use induction over the naturals, or even state the theorems that require such a proof. (An example of the difference between classical and strict finitism: classical finitism allows us to talk about the limit of an infinite sequence, because one can phrase this as a statement about *finite truncations* of the sequence becoming arbitrarily close to the limit, but strict finitists only want to talk about finite sequences in the first place.)

Then there's [Ultrafinitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism), which goes as far as to deny the existence of *sufficiently large* natural numbers. For this school of thought, it's not good enough to say "in principle, given enough time, we could write down a finite proof of such and such a statement." One has to be able to write this proof down *in practice*. This is somewhat like [Constructivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)), although I believe most constructivists accept the existence of infinite sets.

Finitist positions may seem ridiculous at first glance (and they are decidedly fringe among working mathematicians), but to be fair to them, most people do not have an easy or satisfying answer to the question of what the existence of a mathematical object really means. If you ask me whether the number 5 exists, I will say "it depends what you mean by exist." If you ask me whether the natural numbers exist, I will give you the same answer. When I prove an existence theorem for a differential equation, I am (in my own mind) only making a mathematical statement, not a philosophical one. But if you talk to finitists, they at least have a notion of what they mean, philosophically, when they say that something exists. Most mathematicians (including me) don't even address the question.

Finally, there is also a non-ideological case to be made for more restrictive frameworks: namely, it is interesting to learn what mathematics can still be built with fewer tools at our disposal.

Comment: For my understanding, can you explain the difference between strict finitism and ultrafinitism? I thought they were synonymous: the claim that sufficiently large finite sets are not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I appreciate the point about finitist positions and the difficulty of knowing what a mathematical object is.

Comment: @user4894 As I understand it, strict finitists are comfortable with any set or number that is finite, no matter how large or how impractical to write down or calculate.

Comment: @jobermark To clarify your statement, would you characterize prominent ultrafinitists like Doron Zeilberger and the late Edward Nelson as nuts?

Comment: @user4894. I don't think either of them deny the existence of any given number.  So by the definition given in this post, neither of them would be Ultrafinitist.  If that definition is wrong here too, and I will only get flak for pointing that out, I will just go away.

Comment: @jobermark I don't know much about ultrafinitism but I find it interesting.  From what little I understand, they are NOT saying that "There is some number N such that there is no N + 1." They are not saying that nor are they so naive (the sane ones) as to think that's sensible. In fact you are right that some and perhaps many people who consider themselves ultrafinitists are insane. It's just that there actually are some sane ones. And their point as I understand it is that *Exponentiation is not a total function*. (continued)

Comment: What that means is, say we have the expression N = 2^2^2^2^2^2, which represents a number so far beyond anything that could exist in the physical world that it is purely hypothetical. Now given the Peano axioms, the question is, *can we get to N via successor operations*? And THAT is the core question of ultrafinitism, as I understand it. Suppose we start counting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... *How would we know when to stop*?

Comment: @user4894 In this context, I am using the definition the author of the post is giving.  Both of your examples do not meet this definition.  Norton is ambivalent about whether our notions of infinite are not simply circular and pointless (his main work IST involves inexhaustible supplies of objects that he just avoids calling infinite), and Zielberger rejects algorithms with uncomputable orders of growth as not being constructive.  Those are good points, but to tag them as being about 'the existence of numbers' is overkill.

Comment: @user4894 To my mind, this is all vocabulary and psychology.  There is a continuum of folks who realize there are better and worse ways of proving things, and we would do better to stick with the better ones.  But at the point you decide 'not as good as possible' means 'false', you are just picking a fight.  I can be an intuitionist and still understand what Cantor means by a limit cardinal.  I consider such math risky, not false.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, the principle of mathematical induction says that you can reach any natural number by repeated succession starting at zero. So, if you want to define the set of natural numbers, then induction must hold on that set.

Note that the principle induction can hold even on finite sets, e.g. on X={0,1} with 0=/=1 and a successor function S such that S(0)=1 and S(1)=0. Induction holds on X since all elements of X can be reach by repeated succession starting at 0. More formally, it would then be trivial to prove:

For all subsets P of X, if 0 in P and for all x in P, we also have S(x) in P, then P = X.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that most flavours of mathematical induction and co-induction can be obtained as as theorems about least and greatest fixed-points of monotonic functions on lattices. Specifically, they can be obtained as corollaries of the [Knaster-Tarski Fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem#Consequences:_least_and_greatest_fixed_points).
Section 21.1 of Pierce's [Types and Programming Languages](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) gives a great summary of this.

So while there may be legitimate reasons to reject mathematical induction philosophically, one has to reject the premises/axioms that allow for it to be  proven. This is similar to how one who rejects [Banach-Tarski's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) method of turning one ball into two should reject the premise that allowed for the result to be provde (the axiom of choice), as opposed to the result itself.

Answer (score 0):

The main 'problem' with (non-transfinite) induction is that the proof itself that would cover all the numbers is not completed in a finite length unless one includes a rule that is implicitly infinitely long.

The proof via induction sets up a program that reduces each step to a previous one, which means that the actual proof for any given case n is roughly n times the length of the stated proof.  The total proof, to cover all cases is then implicitly infinite in length.  But for any case that comes to hand, we could do the scutwork and spit out a proof that is still finite.  So does a collection of infinitely many finite proofs count as a proof?  Well, that depends on why on earth you think there is an infinite set of proofs to begin with.  Either you think there is a complete, infinite set of integers, or you don't.  Either way, induction it true, but it is true for a different reason in each case.

In Classical mathematics, the question seems very stark: you either need the 'induction schema' which is either second-order, and thus potentially self-referential, or has infinitely many entries.  But this is because classical mathematics is not 'constructive', it always models time by taking up space, by creating copies of objects, rather than by taking up time.

If you need something to be true of any integer, but your statement systematically differs from integer to integer, so that there is not a single closed form that captures it, then you have to make infinitely many copies of it, and modify each copy.  This makes induction seem strange.  But it all takes care of itself.  If you think the set of numbers exist, there is no reason why your infinite set of axioms should not exist, one for each number.

From a constructivist point of view, mathematics should be represented not by true statements but by iterative constructions.  A proof should be a program that runs on inputs and verifies that an assertion can be reduced to agreed principles.  Then every proof shares that form with an induction.  We very seldom ever write out a proof proceeding entirely from axioms one step at a time.  Instead, we invoke principles and forms that indirectly indicate how the 'real underlying' proof would be assembled.

And selecting a number does not require embodying the set of all numbers so that you can then choose one.  It just means what it says, if I counted up to someplace and just stopped anywhere, I would have chosen an arbitrary integer without vouching for the existence of a set of all integers.  Our notions of infinite sets are just tricks of language, not depictions of infinite objects.

So issues of infinities do not have to enter into the consideration here.  You only need to accept that iteration is a reasonable thing to do.  You can do that within your definition of what a construction is, and therefore within the definition of what it means to prove something.  In that case, you do not need an infinite axiom base to support proofs with loops.

For Kleene, a proof is a recursive function that computes a truth value, for Bishop it is an iterative process that validates an assertion.  Both of these automatically include induction as a natural form of proof.

Beyond this, there are extreme forms of objection to repetition.  The idea that there is a natural limit on the human ability to keep track of things and that we should not allow arbitrarily long processes into our plans.  This reaction arises quite naturally in the proof of the 4-color theorem, where there are over a thousand separate cases, and each case is an algorithm that reduces a complex structure to one of the earlier cases.  It is a proof that no human could ever possibly comprehend, and our faith in it relies upon our understanding of the engineering process that selected those cases and automatically wrote those algorithms through brute force enumeration.  It makes one worry.

But in such a framework no general mathematical truth is ever really true.  A notion like the idea of induction is impossible to state, and so is a simple theorem like the idea all maps can be painted in four colors.  There are surely maps too complex for a human to paint them, so surely there is no way of knowing about that.  To me, this is nonsense.  We have invented computers, and they collectively manage exobytes of information.  We have more than enough power to handle mathematical truths far beyond any individual's or group's ability to fully comprehend them, and yet we don't doubt that we can enforce the rules that handle that information.  This philosophy has to just crumble under observed reality.

Answer (score -1):

Mathematical induction is a powerful method to prove properties of natural numbers. If you prove a property for the first natural number 1 and if you prove that the natural number *n* + 1 has this property whenever the natural number *n* has this property (of course without fixing *n*) then every natural number has this property. Because you can put *n* = 1 and get the property for *n* + 1 = 2, then you can put *n* = 2, and so on.

This powerful method is a basic tool of mathematics. Nevertheless there is a philosophical position not accepting this, namely that of Cantor's set theory. The reader may be surprised to find set theory differing from mathematics, but the refusal of mathematical induction and Cantor's own words prove this case: Cantor said (on more than one occasion, for more see https://www.hs-augsburg.de/~mueckenh/Transfinity/Transfinity/pdf)

"The general set theory [...] definitely belongs to metaphysics. [...] and the fact that my presently written work is issued in mathematical journals does not modify the metaphysical contents and character of this work. [...] By me Christian philosophy is for the first time confronted with the true teachings of the infinite in its beginnings." [G. Cantor, letter to T. Esser (15 Feb 1896)]

Cantor assumes that infinity can be finished. For instance in a letter to Lipschitz he said (more can be found loc cit) "The erroneous in Gauss' letter consists in his sentence that the *finished infinite* could not become an object of mathematical consideration. [...] The *finished infinite* can be found, in a sense, in the numbers ..." [G. Cantor, letter to R. Lipschitz (19 Nov 1883)]
(my italics)

How can the infinite be finished? For instance, how can the equinumerousity of natural and rational numbers be proved? Only by refusing mathematical induction. There we prove the important property of every natural number *n*: *n* belongs to a finite initial sequence which is followed by an infinity of natural numbers. There is never an end and there is never a finish that would allow anybody to claim equinumerousity with another infinite set. Set theory however does not accept this proof by mathematical induction but claims that somehow simultaneously the infinite can be finished. "Simultaneously" in order to neglect the fact that the sequence of natural numbers has an order and mathematics allows (and in doubt demands) to interrupt the sequence at every position.

There are other philosophies like ultrafinitism not accepting mathematical induction but that is based on arguments about reality and is certainly less severe than Cantor's metaphysics.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75742/discussion-on-answer-by-wilhelm-validity-of-mathematical-induction).